# How to understand stream in Haskell

Tags: haskell, stream, functional-programming

I'm reading 《Learn you a Haskell for Great Good》chapter 9: Input and Output. There is an example code for explaining stream:

```
main = do   
  withFile "something.txt" ReadMode (\handle -> do  
    contents <- hGetContents handle  
    putStr contents)
```

The books says :

> That's why in this case it actually reads a line, prints it to the
>   output, reads the next line, prints it, etc.

But in previous content, for the same example, it also says:

> That's really cool because we can treat contents as the whole contents
>   of the file, but it's not really loaded in memory.

I'm new to functional programming and I'm really confused about this, why we can take `contents` as the whole contents if it reads one line in one time? I though the `contents` in `contents <- hGetContents handle` is just the content of one line, does Haskell save the content of every line into temporary memory or something else?

Comment: ([relevant section](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#files-and-streams)). The first quote from a section concerned with __buffering__. `hGetContents` still gets all content from the file (lazily).

Comment: That snippet uses a concept named  "lazy IO" to return something which looks as a string, but is actually more like a string-producer which will read from the file as soon as more characters are accessed in the string. While convenient, this feature is considered a wart by some Haskellers, since it allows to mix pure computation and side effects (file reading) in a possibly fragile way. For the time being, you can ignore this problem, but know that for non-toy programs, much better libraries exist (e.g. conduit or pipes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **why we can take contents as the whole contents if it reads one line in one time?**

First note that it is not necessary that the content is being read line by line (although it can be possible, I will come to that later). What the author meant is that even though the entire file is not loaded to the memory, you can *assume* conceptually that the variable `contents` has the whole content of the file. This is possible because of the lazy streaming of the file (If you are more interested, you can see the [source](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.4/base-4.8.2.0/src/GHC-IO-Handle.html#hGetBuffering) to see the low level details. It basically uses `unsafeInterleaveIO` to achieve this).

> **does Haskell save the content of every line into temporary memory or something else?**

That depends on the type of buffering used. According to the documentation it depends on the underlying file system:

> The default buffering mode when a handle is opened is
>   implementation-dependent and may depend on the file system object
>   which is attached to that handle. For most implementations, physical
>   files will normally be block-buffered and terminals will normally be
>   line-buffered.

But you can use `hGetBuffering :: Handle -> IO BufferMode` to see yourself what buffering mode you are in.

Answer (score 2):

> How to understand stream in Haskell

You can think of it *as a function* which when invoked, returns *some* of the result (*not all of it*) along with a *call back function* to get the rest when you *need it*. So technically it gives you the entire content, but one chunk at a time, and only if you ask for the rest of it.

If Haskell did not have [*non-strict semantics*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Non-strict_semantics), you could implement this concept by something like:

```
data Stream a = Stream [a] (() -> Stream a)

instance (Show a) => Show (Stream a) where
    show (Stream xs _) = show xs ++ " ..."

rest :: Stream a -> Stream a -- ask for the rest of the stream
rest (Stream _ f) = f ()
```

Then say you want a stream which iterates integers. You can return the first 3 and postpone the rest until the user asks for it:

```
iter :: Int -> Stream Int
iter x = Stream [x, x + 1, x + 2] (\_ -> iter (x + 3))
```

then,

```
\> iter 0
[0,1,2] ...
```

but if you keep asking for the rest, you get the entire content

```
\> take 5 $ iterate rest (iter 0)
[[0,1,2] ...,[3,4,5] ...,[6,7,8] ...,[9,10,11] ...,[12,13,14] ...]
```

or

```
\> let go (Stream [i, j, k] _) acc = i:j:k:acc
\> take 20 . foldr go [] $ iterate rest (iter 0)
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
```

That is the same story with *line buffering* under the hood. It reads and returns the first line, but then you can ask for the next line, and the next line, ... So technically you get the entire content even though it only reads one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `hGetHandle` itself never reads *anything*; it simply returns an `IO` action that, when ultimately executed, will read from the file. When combined with `putStr` with `hGetContents handle >>= putStr` (which is simply the `do` notation desugared), you get an IO action that takes a handle and outputs its contents to the screen. At no point in the Haskell program itself do you ever specify *how* that happens; it is entirely up to the Haskell runtime and how it executes the `IO` action you create.